# How to count number of tuples with a specific value per group?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, count

Consider the following schema:

```
Game(gameID, name, developID, cost, category),
Developer(developerID, name, country, speciality )
```

Now I want to find out number of games developed by American developer in each category.
My attempt is as follows:

```
select category, count(developID) as TotalGames
from Game join Developer on developerID = developID
where country = 'America'
group by category;
```

Now the problem here is that this query does not show the categories in which no American developer has developed any game. But I want it to show that category with *TotalGames* = 0

So how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the other answer uses a CTE, it is not necessary. You can filter directly in the join clause.

**You need to change the join to a `left join`, and put the filter within the `on`.**

> Note: You should use table aliases, they make the query easier to comprehend

```sql
select g.category, count(d.developerID) as TotalGames
from Game g
left join Developer d on d.developerID = g.developID and d.country = 'America'
group by g.category;
```

**Do not** make the mistake of putting the `country` filter in the `where`, it will not work.